# How do ensure that Apache AJP to Tomcat connection is secure/encrypted?

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, ajp

We want to front-end our Tomcat instance with an Apache instance (running on the same machine) that will be serving everything on HTTPS and connect Apache to Tomcat using AJP. When using AJP, do we need to do anything to make sure that the connection between Apache and Tomcat is secure? (We dont want passwords to be sniffable on the network between Apache and Tomcat). The O/S is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are saying

> Tomcat instance with an Apache instance (running on the same machine)

and later you are saying

> We dont want passwords to be sniffable on the network between Apache and Tomcat

This just contradicts each other.

EDIT: AJP [is not designed to be secure](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Secure-AJP-over-ssl-td2083890.html), if you need security, use `mod_proxy_http` and proxy over https, or create SSH tunnel. Needless to say, you will have to pay for this overhead.

Comment: Well, therein lies the question-- is the tech that enables Apache to Tomcast communications going to go back through the network at all. There are ways you could configure a web server to go back through the network even if what its connecting to in the back-end is on the same machine.

Answer (score 6):

When using AJP you *cannot* do anything to ensure it is secure. It isn't. There is no SSL version. You would have to use HTTPS. AJP is designed for the usual case where HTTPD and Tomcat are in the same private LAN and security isn't an issue.